# Find the newest JSON file in my directory and confirm the contents Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, find, readfile

I want to be able to find the newest `.json` file in my directory, and then look through the file and search for `"status": "PASSED"` inside of it. Is this possible to do inside of Mac terminal?

So far I have the following:
`find data/results -type f -mmin -60 | grep '.json'`

Note: This command will always output just one JSON file.

Which will print in my terminal the name of the latest `.json` file, but I can't figure out how to then read It.

Thank you in advance!

JSON File looks like:

```
[
    {
        ...,
        "fieldName": "Answer",
        "status": "PASSED",
        "otherFieldName": "OtherAnswer",
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: Include a sample input representing the common structure of your JSON files. Also, is it certain that that command will always list a **single** file?

Comment: @oguzismail Yes It's guaranteed to only output a single file, and I included a sample of the JSON in the question!

Comment: Something like `find data/results -name '*.json' -mmin -60 -exec grep -F '"status": "PASSED"' {} \;`?

Comment: @oguzismail perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the newest json file in a directory, you can do `ls -t *.json | head -n1`. Your command (the `find … grep`) is similar, although it can output more than one file if the dates are close together. The command I suggest will always find only the newest.

To grep that file for the passing status, of course you would do `grep PASSED <file>`.

To combine these commands, as with all things Terminal, there are many ways to do it. One option would be:

```
ls -t *.json | head -n1 | xargs grep PASSED
```

Another option would be:

```
grep PASSED "$(ls -t *.json | head -n1)"
```

The result will be the same.

The techniques I'm introducing you to here are "xargs", which takes lines of input and adds them on to the end of the command as parameters, and "command substitution" (the `$()` construct), which substitutes that part of the command for the result of a separate command within it.